# OnclickListener in a Dialog Android

Tags: android, button, dialog, onclicklistener

Hi I'm developing an app in which I'm using a dialog on an activity, the Dialog has one button but when i want to use OnClickListener (from the activity) it doesn't work.  I tried searching on the internet for a solution for this problem but I couldn't find a proper way to implement it. So can any one please suggest a way of doing this...

```
public void btnStartDialog(View view) {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
    final VideoView videoview = (VideoView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video);
    videoview.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoview.start();
    videoview.requestFocus();

    final Button stop = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnStop);

    stop.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    videoview.stopPlayback();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

    dialog.show();
    Thread timerThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(34800);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                videoview.stopPlayback();
                dialog.dismiss();
                //close();
            }
        }
    };
    timerThread.start();

}
```

THE BTN XML :

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:src="@drawable/fab_plus"
    app:backgroundTint="#d20b0d"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:elevation="10dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    android:onClick="btnStartDialog"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
```

Comment: Move `dialog.show();` below the clickListener.

Comment: keep  your line of code dialog.show() ; in above the  final Button stop = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnStop); line (or) below the onclicklistener

Comment: Not working, the same problem :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Show the dialog after `stop.setOnClickListener` like,

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);

   //Your codes here

    stop.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            videoview.stopPlayback();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

   dialog.show();
```

Comment: @AdrianTesore same error means ? Have you tried toasting anything in the button's click handler ?Are you sure it is called ? or You're getting some error ?

Comment: I have found 2 problems in my code, 1 - dialog.show(); at the end of the onClickListener and 2nd and very stupid problem was that it was a FloatingActionButton xD ! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this way..

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
View view = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog,
            null);
dialog.setContentView(view );

final VideoView videoview = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video);
videoview.setVideoURI(uri);
videoview.start();
videoview.requestFocus();

final Button stop = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnStop);

dialog.show();

stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        videoview.stopPlayback();
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Either call `dialog.show()`; after all the initialization and interface registration, Or to separate the dialog from your activity for making your code modular, you can do to following:

1. Create a `class` extending `Dialog`.
2. Create a `method` in your dialog `class` to accept the `OnClickListener` and save it at `class` level inside dialog `class`.
3. From `activity` after launching that dialog call than method with your `activity's` dialog.
4. In your `Dialog class` set a New `OnClickListener` on your dialog's button.
5. And onclick of that button just manually give callback to `activity's` `OnClickListener`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: "Either call `dialog.show()` after all the initialization and interface registration." that's the point.